# Postgresql: Is there a way to return both table data and output parameters from a stored procedure as in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

In Microsoft Sql Server, both output parameters and select results can be used in cohesion to return data back to the client. This comes handy in use-cases like paging, where you need to return a main set along with associated meta-data like total page count. All the examples I have seen so far in Postgres either return data via output parameters or via table results. I am unable to create a procedure with both together as it fails with the following error:
**ERROR:  OUT and INOUT arguments aren't allowed in TABLE functions**

Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_Test(out p_count int)
RETURNS TABLE (CustomerId int, CustomerName varchar(50))
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerName, Address, Area, Phonenumber, Email, communicationpreference)
    VALUES ('Julie Yellow', 'JY Ad', 'JY Ar', 'JV0987654', 'j@ye.com', 1);

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMERS INTO  p_count;
    SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName FROM Customers;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE exception '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END;
$BODY$
```

Can't they go together? Is there any alternative approach in Postgresql?

Please advice

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no - either you create function returns something or that something is defined by `OUT` parameters.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

> **If you declared the function with output** parameters, write just RETURN
>   with no expression. The **current values of the output parameter
>   variables will be returned**.

ephasis mine.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html

> Also OUT and INOUT arguments cannot be used together with the RETURNS
>   TABLE notation

You can play with `raise info` or `notify` channel though

Answer (score 2):

You can simply include the count in the final query.

But to return a query result from PL/pgSQL you need to use `return query`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test()
   RETURNS TABLE (customerid int, customername varchar(50), newcount int)
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO customers(customername, address, area, phonenumber, email, communicationpreference)
    VALUES ('Julie Yellow', 'JY Ad', 'JY Ar', 'JV0987654', 'j@ye.com', 1);

    return query
      SELECT customerid, customername, count(*) over () as newcount
      FROM customers;
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE exception '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The language name is an identifier, do not put it into single quotes.

---

Alternatively you could return multiple results as refcursors from your function. But this is a bit clumsy to use with most SQL clients:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test()
   returns setof refcursor
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   c1 refcursor;
   c2 refcursor;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO customers(customername, address, area, phonenumber, email, communicationpreference)
    VALUES ('Julie Yellow', 'JY Ad', 'JY Ar', 'JV0987654', 'j@ye.com', 1);

    open c1 for 
      select count(*) from customers;
    return next c1;

    open c2 for 
      SELECT customerid, customername
      FROM customers;
    return next c2;

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE exception '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me in situations like this is to use JSON as a return type. Your example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_Test()
RETURNS JSON
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO Customers(CustomerName, Address, Area, Phonenumber, Email, communicationpreference)
    VALUES ('Julie Yellow', 'JY Ad', 'JY Ar', 'JV0987654', 'j@ye.com', 1);

    SELECT CustomerId, CustomerName FROM Customers;

    RETURN json_build_object(
        'count', (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CUSTOMERS),
        'customers', (
            SELECT json_agg(
                json_build_object('customerId', CustomerId, 'customerName', CustomerName)
            ) 
            FROM Customers
        )
    );
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE exception '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
END;
$BODY$
```